# number of element occurence

Tags: java, hashmap, treeset

I'm trying to find number of element occurrence using treeset and hashmap.
when i'm running the program, value is not increasing in hashmap

I've tried map.put(data,map.get(data)+1) it is causing null pointer exception.

```
public class ReadData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("E:\\new1.txt");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String data = "";
            int count =1;
            HashMap<String,Integer> map = null;
            TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
            set.add("");
            while((data=br.readLine())!=null) {

                 map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            if(set.contains(data)) {
                map.put(data,map.get(data)+1);
                System.out.println("correct");
                System.out.println(count+1);

            }else
            {
                map.put(data,count);
                set.add(data);
                System.out.println("Not correct");
            }
            //System.out.println(map);
             Set sets = map.entrySet();
              Iterator iterator = sets.iterator();
              while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                 Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
                System.out.print("key is: "+ mentry.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
                 System.out.println(mentry.getValue());

              }
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

input:- orange
apple
orange
orange

expeted o/p key is orange & value is 3
key is apple & value is 1

The output is key is: orange & Value is: 1
key is: apple & Value is: 1
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You every time initialize a new map inside of the while loop. So since it is empty, it causes `NullPointerException`, I think.

Comment: I corrected that now i am not getting null pointer exception, still the expected o/p is not coming. I want hashmap key to be updated not create new line

Answer (score 3):

You can do it cleaner using streams, with [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) and [`Collectors.counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--). You should also use `try-with-resource` construct and new `Files` class:

```
String delimiter = " ";
Path p = Paths.get("E:", "file.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(p)) {
    Map<String, Long> result = br.lines()
            .flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(delimiter)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

For `orange apple orange orange` input this code will print `{orange=3, apple=1}`.

Comment: Hi, I am really thanks for your reply, but i want to do it in that format. so could you suggest me to improve my code

Answer (score 0):

Please notices that

```
    HashMap<String,Integer> map = null;
```

is not the same as an empty map. First all you must create a new map before to use it.

It this case use for example

```
        HashMap<String,Integer> map = null;
```

An then you are creating into the loop a new map, this is hard to read for your purpose. I would suggest just instantiate your map together with the set and remove

```
map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

inside while loop

Your code should look like

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
            set.add("");
            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Comment: Hi, now null pointer exception is not coming, still the expected o/p is not coming hashmap key not updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TreeMap instead of using HashMap + TreeSet.

```
public class ReadData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File f = new File("E:\\new1.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            TreeMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap(String, Integer);

            while((String data=br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] fruitNames = data.split(" "); // or regex s+ can also be used

                for(String fruitName : fruitNames){
                    Integer count = map.get(fruitName);
                    Integer newVal = count == null ? 1 : count+1 ;
                    map.put(fruitName, newVal);
                }
                // iterate over keys in TreeMap
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to count the occurrences of a string, you can simply use StringUtils.countMatches from
Apache Commons lang.

```
//First get all the words from your line - 
String[] allWords = data.split("\\s");

//Retrieve unique strings
        String[] uniqueStrings = Arrays.stream(allWords).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);

// Print the occurrence of each string in data
        for (String word: uniqueStrings){

               System.out.println("Count of occurrences for the word " + word + "is: " + StringUtils.countMatches(data, word));
        }
```